# Confusion regarding Simulator and Base SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I want to know whether iPhone Simulator version (i.e. iPhone 5.0 Simulator, iPhone 6.0 Simulator, etc) and Base SDK are related to each other or not?

So, if I develop an App with Base SDK 6.0 and if I test it on iPhone 5 Simulator - does it mean that I am testing it on device with iOS 5.0?

Please let me know.

Comment: BASE SDK 6.0 means that it is for iOS6. The simulator versions may vary and you can test on all simulators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base SDK is an indicator of what APIs your compiler will allow you to use. Deployment Target determins the minimum OS version this app will be allowed to run on. If they differ you need to make sure in code that you only use functions/classes/methods/symbols that already existed on the older OS. or else the app will crash with exceptions like "unrecognized selector"

Your question is imprecise: there is no "iPhone 5 Simulator". There is a Simulator app that can behave like a 4" iPhone 5 on a variety of OS version levels. The Simulator set to iOS 5.x will behave like a device with this OS version would.

Answer (score 1):

**Base SDK**

*The Base SDK is the version of SDK that will be used when compiling your application – the compiler will use the headers and libraries of this specific SDK.*

**iPhone OS Deployment Target**

To specify which OS version is the minimum that your application will support, you set the deployment target. Your application will then run on this minimum OS as well as all later versions.*

For more info check this:-
[Link](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/xcode/base-sdk-and-iphone-os-deployment-target-developing-apps-with-the-4-x-sdk-deploying-to-3-x-devices.html)

Answer (score 0):

Nope. With a base SDK of 6.0 means that you are using a simulator with iOS6.0 like for example if you were to deploy an application with base SDK 6.0 on your mobile device with iOS 5.1 and below, you will not be able to run it